# curl command to upload data from a file to couchbase bucket

Tags: json, curl, command-line-interface, couchbase, libcurl

I have a use-case, where I wanted to upload json data from a file to a couchbase bucket using CURL command.

I am using the below command

```
curl -v localhost:8093/query/service -u Administrator:${password} -d 'statement=INSERT INTO `com.src.test.default` (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "'$docId'" , '`jq -c . local.json`');'
```

However, using the above command, only small size file can be transferred otherwise I am getting some error like this, but json format is good:

```
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 216:
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Isn't the error message self-descriptive? You have to balance quotes.

Comment: in local.json ? But the syntax of file is all good.

Comment: well what's at position 216?

Comment: i m using similar curl command to upsert documents to CB, but if the document contains plus signs (+), they get converted to whitespace. Not sure how to overcome this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are shelling out to flatten your JSON into a single line on the command this may work for small amounts of data but you might have just gone too big.

IMHO sending a large JSON file on the command line just seems wrong (as there are command line limits in Linux), you might look at some of the limits

```
    getconf ARG_MAX
```

But for your true single arg limit on the command line look at MAX_ARG_STRLEN which for my debian system is 131072 from "binfmts.h"

So just test things out WRT argument lengths do the following

```
    /bin/echo "$(printf "%*s" 131071 ".")">/dev/null

    /bin/echo "$(printf "%*s" 131072 ".")">/dev/null
    -bash: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

I needed some moderate large data so I just grabbed some from the net for testing

```
    curl 'https://data.ny.gov/api/views/pxa9-czw8/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ZEEF&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Fjson-datasets.zeef.com%2Fjdorfman' -o local.json

    ls -ltr local.json
    -rw-r--r-- 1 linuxbrew linuxbrew 251492 Jan 10 10:28 local.json
```

What if you did the following not $keyspace is just your oddly named bucket com.src.test.default:

```
    echo 'statement=INSERT INTO `'$keyspace'` (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "'$docId'",' > tmp.cmd
    cat local.json >> tmp.cmd
    echo ');' >> tmp.cmd

    curl -v localhost:8093/query/service -u ${username}:${password} -d @./tmp.cmd
```

But since you are using curl why not use cbimport? You could merely do the following:

```
    jq -c -M . local.json > tmp.json
    /opt/couchbase/bin/cbimport json -c localhost -b "com.src.test.default"  -f lines -g $docId  -d file://./tmp.json
```

Another method you could use:

```
    cat local.json | /opt/couchbase/bin/cbc-create --username $username --password $password --spec 'couchbase://localhost/com.src.test.default' "$docID"
```

Some other thoughts ...

1. The command jq by default colorizes the output as such if you insist on compacting with jq use the -M flag.
2. Your bucket although having a legal name `com.src.test.default` uses the "." character in version 7.0+ will be a keyspace of `com.src.test.default`._default._default the dots in you bucket name caused me a bit of confusion.  Just be aware when you upgrade that we use bucketname.scope.collection where your pre 7.0+ data will be automatically migrated to bucketname._default._default
3. You might consider using an SDK and writing a simple program in you favorite language.

Comment: Using cbimport is the best option however I am only supposed to use curl command due to some restrictions at my workplace. I will also explore the SDK option which looks good option for long term use. Thanks.